# SQL (Find & Replace) Entire Database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

***I am using PHPMYADMIN from SiteGround CPanel.***

---

**Story:** I had Cloudflare setup for a php platform, I then realised it was causing issues so I removed it. The issue I'm left with is that half of my site is still running of (https://www.example.com).

**What I have done so far:** In the config files of my script I have already set it so that it runs through https alone.

**What I want to achieve:** I noticed in the database that there are some fields that are running through the www. I want to execute a command that will automatically find anything with my old domain (https://www.example.com) and replace it with (https://example.com). I noticed that the fields are not all appearing from a single column/file, it is all over the place, so a field&replace overall should fix the issue.

I would appecaite any help. Since it is database I don't wish to try out random things from different websites provding their feedback. I was recommended to use this website for assistance (if possible).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straightforward and quickest way, is to simply take a dump of the entire  database, open the sql dump file in some text editor, and then do a text replace from [old url] to [new url]. Then import the dump file back to the database. This should work just fine and avoid the headache of uncertainty and risk over doing a write operation on the entire database's tables via some db query.